# Question about surjectivity of operator in $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm wondering about this thing: I have

\begin{equation}
T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Tx_n = \frac{1}{n}x_n
\end{equation}

I need to prove that $T$ is injective but not surjective and that $Rg(T)$ is dense in $\ell^2$. For injectivity I have:

\begin{equation}
Tx_n = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{n}x_n = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_n \equiv 0
\end{equation}

so I think I'm done.

For surjectivity, what came in mind immediately, is that knowing that $x_n, 1/n$ belong to $\ell^2$ their product is in $\ell^1$ (By Holder). So by this quick reasonment, I should conclude that $Rg(T) = \ell^1$ which is dense in $\ell^2$. But my question is:

Can I entirely cover $\ell^1$ by $\frac{1}{n}x_n$ (Both in $\ell^2$)? Probably this is trivial but I was just wondering about it.

Comment: Hint for the actual question: you just need to find some $(x_n)\in\ell^2$ such that $(nx_n)\not\in\ell^2$. This shouldn't be especially hard. For your question about $\ell^1$: your question is equivalent to the following: is there a $(y_n)\in\ell^1$ such that $ny_n\not\in\ell^2$.

Comment: This question already has an answer.

Comment: Where can I find it? Didn't know about

Answer (score 1):

The range of $T$ is the set of all the sequences $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ such that the sequence $(nx_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ belongs to $\ell^2$. Indeed, if  $(nx_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ belongs to $\ell^2$ then let $a_n=nx_n$ and show that $T((a_n)_{n\geqslant 1})=(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ hence $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is in the range of $T$. THe converse is not harder.

In particular, the range of $T$ contains the sequences whose only finitely many terms do not vanish and this set is dense in $\ell^2$.